# Nativescript Webview issue

Tags: webview, telerik, nativescript

I am trying to bundle my hosted website into a mobile application by using nativescript's webview. While everything works as expected, it doesn't render some of the 3D Secure pages. When my site redirects for payment a blank page renders.

I read some articles that point this may be related to the cache of WKWebView but not sure what the issue is.

I am using native-script 4.0.1 my one line code is as follows;

```
<WebView src='https://www.bank3dsecurepage.com'></WebView>
```

Btw; this works fine when i use Telerik's preview app.

Answer (score 1):

Nicklliev from nativescript-angular github repo solved this issue by pointing out NSAppTransportSecurity configuration in App_Resources/iOS/info.plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```